# Obtaining CoreLocation in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I am trying to obtain current user location through my app. I wrote all delegate methods, added strings in info.plist but still it is not calling the delegate methods. Please help me.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER){
        NSUInteger code = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
        if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined &&([self.locationManager  respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)] || [self.locationManager   respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])) {
            // choose one request according to your business.
            if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"]){
                [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            } else if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"]) {
                [self.locationManager  requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Info.plist does not contain NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription");
            }
        }
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of added keys in my app info.plist]
[image: Error finding keys]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console logs itself says that **you are missing to add appropriate Keys** in *info.plist* file 
You are supposed to add

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

keys with relevant description and then make a request from user to allow access.

This [link](http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/getting-gps-location-using-core-location-in-ios-8-vs-ios-7/) might be helpful.

Since you have already added these keys try following

1. Remove the keys and re-add.
2. Once done try to do a clean and then build you application.

Comment: I did this. I deleted the keys and re-added but still same error. I do not know, why?

Comment: Simply adding your code in a new projects works fine for me. Which OS version are you using to test the application ?

Comment: Try commenting the if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) check because this is the only thing I tried different than your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it starts working now. "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" was not added properly.